EC2 instances cannot connect to Stripe when behind an ALB
I was deploying my NodeJS backend that integrates Stripe payment. When the user on the frontend clicks on the Checkout button, the backend API simply calls Stripe SDK to create a checkout session and the user is redirected to the Stripe checkout page. I tested it locally and everything worked as expected.
When launching a service to run containers on EC2 behind an ALB, the frontend is able to make API calls to the backend smoothly on most of the endpoints. However, it failed to connect to Stripe. Once the checkout button had been clicked, nothing happened. After a while waiting, I checked the log of the running tasks and got the following output:
[Nest] 28 - 06/01/2024, 4:54:13 AM ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Request aborted due to timeout being reached (80000ms) 
Error: Request aborted due to timeout being reached (80000ms)   
at /app/node_modules/stripe/cjs/RequestSender.js:326:37 
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)   

To solve the problem, I removed the load balancer and only had an EC2 instance running on port 5000. I changed the network mode in the task definition from awsvpc to bridge and did static port mapping, then ran a single task. To my surprise, the frontend could reach the checkout endpoint seamlessly. The problem arises when I place an ALB behind EC2 instances when launching a service on ECS.
EC2 instances are placed in public subnets by default, to pull the image from ECR. Therefore, I supposed the problem must be related to security groups. Here's my security groups configuration:
ALB
Inbound rules

Outbound rules

EC2 instances
Inbound rules

Outbound rules

So is there a way to address this issue when EC2 instances are behind an ALB?

It looks like your ALB does not allow connections from the public internet to its port 443 (HTTPS). Also, you should change its outbound rules to 0.0.0.0/0. If it does not work, you will have to describe how you've configured your ALB listener rules and target groups.
What's good is that the inbound rules of the underlying EC2's security group permits the ALB's security group. However, its too permissive due to the entire port range being opened and I'd recommend to narrow that down to port 5000 or whatever HTTP port you are using 80, 8000 or 8080.

Thanks for your solution. I tried to adjust the rules in the security groups like you mentioned, but the problem still persists. I've previously set everything up with HTTPS in a large project, but this problem arose and it was hard to figure out the cause of the issue. Therefore, I decided to create a minimal reproduction of this problem by only having an API endpoint that integrates Stripe to see if the EC2 instance actually connects to Stripe, and the problem occurred. The frontend also suffered from a CORS error while normally it doesn't. I'll probably give AWS Lambda a try.

@TranThaiAnh, what version of Stripe SDK are you using?

I'm using the 10/04/2024 version of Stripe SDK.
